# SFTP server hosting library for .NET Core / 5 / 6

Tags: gratis, c#, .net, sftp

Is there a library to host a SFTP server from .NET Core / 5 / 6? I found this one but it costs money

https://www.rebex.net/file-server/

Basically I need a very simple library were I can host a SFTP and have a virtual in-memory filesystem.